# Are glands in human made up of muscles?

Tags: endocrinology, muscles, movement

I came across this idea while reading an excerpt of my textbook $-$

> Muscles move eye lid , tongue, beat the heart, popel food through gut, discharge wastes, squeeze out secretion from the glands etc.

But I don't understand how this happen ? Does glands really squeeze out hormones?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No they are not made of muscles. Glands are modified epithelial tissues. Glands are basically of two types Endocrine and Exocrine glands.

- **Endocrine gland**

It is a gland that lacks a duct system. The secretions are directly
   poured into the bloodstream. They secrete hormones through exocytosis mostly.

- **Exocrine gland**

It is a gland with a duct system. The secretions(sweat, sebum,saliva
   etc) are transported onto a surface of the body (e.g skin or lumen of GI tract) by
   ducts.***Exocrine glands may be controlled by muscles [at the duct level](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=er-lpJJ0XLgC&pg=PA498&dq=saliva%20primarily%20through%20smooth%20muscle%20contraction%20at%20the%20duct%20level&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwil9Ofc2cjOAhVENo8KHc75DpAQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=saliva%20primarily%20through%20smooth%20muscle%20contraction%20at%20the%20duct%20level&f=false).***

There are three types of exocrine glands based on the process of secretion of chemical substance at a cellular level$-$

- Apocrine gland

It is a gland in which the apical portion of the secretory cells are distintegrated to release the chemical. e.g- Apocrine sweat gland

- Holocrine gland

It is a gland in which the secretory cells are completely disintegrated to release the chemical.e.g.- Sebaceous gland

- Merocrine gland

It is a gland in which the secretory cells remain intact and the chemical is 
released through exocytosis.e.g.- salivary gland

[image]

Reference:

- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gland)
- [ncbi](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18669645)